# how to install ubuntu from USB before the existing OS is booting

Tags: installation, boot, usb

i have a windowsXP OS, but the system down and i can't open it, so i decide to install ubuntu.
i installed it in my USB 
how to force the computer to boot and read from flash and install the ubuntu, without opening the windowsXP system ??

Comment: You dont need to install ubuntu to use it. You can create a LiveUSB from which you can directly boot and use the system without actually installing the OS.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer sign ACER, and before booting OS you should press F12.
Then you will say Boot menu - choose Hardware and then FLASDISK.

But it dont have to work also on your pc.

Comment: i installed ubontu in my USB and extract it.
does the computer understand that i want to install the OS ???

Comment: USB = Flashdisk. Computer will understand, if you have on it ISO live image of current version

Comment: no i don't have it in IOS version .. how to make it like that  ?

Comment: for ubuntu 12.04  - maybe here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Comment: does i do it using ULTraIOS program ???

Comment: I think no. I donth think you need it for something. You need ISO image not IOS..

Comment: this is my mistake iam sorry the program is ultraISO .it is for make an image 
but first should i have to unzip the folder then make it as .ISO then copy it to my flash ?

Comment: Just download iso file (you should pay attention, there are vesions for 32 and 64 bit computers).. after download copy it to the flash. I think that you will not need to unzip. It is not folder.